# My method PurchaseVents() is getting the value = 0 of variables totalCost12 & vCountAmount instead of values they achieved in function AddCount()

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have declared following variables globally.

```
economy_worth;
Covid_PT;
totalCost12;
vCountAmount;
```

[Variable Declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMOnP.png)

Have written the public function AddCount() and AddPrice() which will change the values of totalCost12 and vCountAmount. Which Actually does and shows through Debug.Log().

[Methods: AddCount & AddPrice()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di7kv.png)

On the other hand, I have written another public function PurchaseVents() to change the values of economy_worth and Covid_PT using values of totalCost12 & vCountAmount. But this method is unable to change anything as it is getting value = zero for both totalCost12 and vCountAmount. Can anyone tell why this function is getting value zero for both variables?

[Method: PurchaseVents()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1Fim.png)

Values of vCountAmount and totalCost12 changes as I press Plus(+) button.
[Debug.Log() of both variables after pressing Plus(+)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k8qg.png)
But When I run PurchaseVents() Method, it's not getting the updated value of vCountAmount and totalCost12 but zero.
[Debug.Log() of vCountAmount and totalCost12 in PurchaseVents()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWayT.png)

Full code is below:

```
public class Game_Manager : MonoBehaviour
{   //COVID HOSPITAL
    public Text CovidPT;
    public Text CovidHealth;
    public int Covid_PT;
    public string covid_health;

    //NATIONAL BANK
    public Text economyWorth;
    public Text economyHealth;
    public int economy_worth;
    public string economy_health;

    //SOCIETY OFFICE / RESTRICTION
    public Text restriction;
    public string restrc;

    //MARKET
    public Text CovidBudget;
    public int Covid_Budget;

    //POPULATION/RESIDENTIAL AREA
    public int population;
    public Text pop;
    public string ph;
    public Text phealth;

    //TAX COLLECTION
    public int Tax_amount;
    public Text TaxAmount;

    //OVERALL PERFORMANCE
    public string performance;
    public Text performancehealth;

    //VENTILATOR PURCHASE
    public Text vCount;
    public Text vCost;
    public int vCountAmount;
    public int totalCost12;
    public int valueCopy;

    //VACCINE PURCHASE
    public Text vacCount;
    public Text vacCost;
    public int vacCountAmount;
    public int totalCostVac;

    //MASK PURCHASE
    public Text maskCount;
    public Text maskCost;
    public int maskCountAmount;
    public int totalCostMask;

    //SHELTER PURCHASE
    public Text shelterCount;
    public Text shelterCost;
    public int shelterCountAmount;
    public int totalCostShelter;
    //REWARDS
    public int claim1st = 50000;
    public int claim2nd = 30000;
    public int claim3rd = 20000;
    public int claim4th = 10000;
    public int claim5th = 6000;
    public int claim6th = 3000;
    public int claim7th = 1500;


    void Start()
    {
        
        //COVID PATEINTS
        Covid_PT = 9000;
        CovidPT.text = Covid_PT.ToString();
     //   CovidPT = GetComponent<Text>();
        if (Covid_PT < 8000)
        {
            covid_health = "Good";
            CovidHealth.text = covid_health.ToString();
     //       CovidHealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else
        if (Covid_PT > 8100 || Covid_PT < 12100)
        {
            covid_health = "Bad";
            CovidHealth.text = covid_health.ToString();
     //       CovidHealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else
            if (Covid_PT > 12100)
        {
            covid_health = "Worst";
            CovidHealth.text = covid_health.ToString();
    //        CovidHealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }

        //NATIONAL BANK
       // economy_worth = 900000;
        economyWorth.text = economy_worth.ToString();
       // economyWorth = GetComponent<Text>();

        if (economy_worth > 1000000)
        {
            economy_health = "Excellent";
            economyHealth.text = economy_health.ToString();
           // economyHealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else
        if (economy_worth > 800000)
        {
            economy_health = "Good";
            economyHealth.text = economy_health.ToString();
           // economyHealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else
            if (economy_worth < 800000)
        {
            economy_health = "Bad";
            economyHealth.text = economy_health.ToString();
           // economyHealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }

        //RESTRICTION
        restrc = " Mild Lockdown";
        restriction.text = restrc.ToString();
 //       restriction = GetComponent<Text>();


        //MARKET
        Covid_Budget = (int)(0.01 * economy_worth);
        CovidBudget.text = Covid_Budget.ToString();
     //   CovidBudget = GetComponent<Text>();

        //POPULATION / RESIDENTIAL AREA
        population = 160000;
        pop.text = population.ToString();
     //   pop = GetComponent<Text>();

        if (population < 160000)
        {
            ph = "Bad Decrease";
            phealth.text = ph.ToString();
         //   phealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else
        if (population >= 160000)
        {
            ph = "Mild Decrease";
            phealth.text = ph.ToString();
         //   phealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else
            if (population >= 200000)
        {
            ph = "No Decrease";
            phealth.text = ph.ToString();
        //    phealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }

        //TAX COLLECTION
        Tax_amount = (int)(0.8 * population);
        TaxAmount.text = Tax_amount.ToString();
        //TaxAmount = GetComponent<Text>();

        //PERFORMANCE  HEALTH      
        if (economy_health == "Good" && covid_health == "Good" && ph == "No Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Excellent";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
         //   performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Good" && covid_health == "Worst" && ph == "Bad Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Worst";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
          //  performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Good" && covid_health == "Good" && ph == "Mild Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Good";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
          //  performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Good" && covid_health == "Good" && ph == "Bad Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Unsatisfactory";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
        //    performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Good" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "No Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Satisfactroy";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
           // performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Good" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "Mild Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Unsatisfactory";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
       //     performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Good" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "Bad Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Bad";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
      //      performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Good" && covid_health == "Worst" && ph == "No Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Satisfactory";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
        //    performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Good" && covid_health == "Worst" && ph == "Mild Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Unsatisfactory";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
        //    performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Good" && covid_health == "Worst" && ph == "Bad Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Bad";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
       //     performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Bad" && covid_health == "Good" && ph == "No Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Good";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
        //    performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Bad" && covid_health == "Good" && ph == "Mild Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Satisfactory";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
       //     performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Bad" && covid_health == "Good" && ph == "Bad Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Bad";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
       //    performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Bad" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "No Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Unsatisfactory";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
       //     performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Bad" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "Mild Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Unsatisfactory";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
      //      performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Bad" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "Bad Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Bad";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
      //      performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Bad" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "No Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Unsatisfactory";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
      //      performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Bad" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "Mild Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Unsatisfactory";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
      //      performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Bad" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "Bad Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Bad";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
     //       performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Bad" && covid_health == "Worst" && ph == "No Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Bad";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
     //       performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Bad" && covid_health == "Worst" && ph == "Mild Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Worst";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
    //        performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Bad" && covid_health == "Worst" && ph == "Bad Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Worst";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
     //       performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Worst" && covid_health == "Good" && ph == "No Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Unsatisfactory";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
      //      performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Worst" && covid_health == "Good" && ph == "Mild Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Unsatisfactory";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
       //     performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Worst" && covid_health == "Good" && ph == "Bad Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Bad";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
       //     performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Worst" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "No Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Bad";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
      //      performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Worst" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "Mild Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Bad";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
        //    performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else

        if (economy_health == "Worst" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "Bad Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Worst";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
       //     performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else
        if (economy_health == "Worst" && covid_health == "Worst" && ph == "No Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Bad";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
     //       performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else
        if (economy_health == "Worst" && covid_health == "Worst" && ph == "Mild Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Worst";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
     //       performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else
        if (economy_health == "Worst" && covid_health == "Bad" && ph == "Bad Decrease")
        {
            performance = "Worst";
            performancehealth.text =
                performance.ToString();
     //       performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }
        else
        {
            performance = "Not Sure";
            performance.ToString();
      //      performancehealth = GetComponent<Text>();
        }


        //VENTILATOR PURCHASE
      //  vCount = GetComponent<Text>();
       // vCost = GetComponent<Text>();

        //VACCINE PURCHASE
      //  vacCount = GetComponent<Text>();
      //  vacCost = GetComponent<Text>();

        //MASK PURCHASE
      //  maskCount = GetComponent<Text>();
      //  maskCost = GetComponent<Text>();

        //SHELTER PURCHASE
      //  shelterCount = GetComponent<Text>();
      //  shelterCost = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    // M    E    T    H    O    D   S

    //VENTILATOR PURCHASE
    public void AddCount()
    {
        vCountAmount++;
        vCount = GetComponent<Text>();
        vCount.text = vCountAmount.ToString();
        Debug.Log("Num of vents: " + vCountAmount);
    }
    public void AddPrice()
    {
        //valueCopy = 1800;
        totalCost12 += 1800;
        
      

        vCost = GetComponent<Text>();
        vCost.text = totalCost12.ToString();
        Debug.Log("total cost is: " + totalCost12);
       
    }

    public void SubtractCount()
    {
        if (vCountAmount >= 1)
        {
            vCountAmount -= 1;
            vCount = GetComponent<Text>();
            vCount.text = vCountAmount.ToString();
            Debug.Log(vCountAmount);
        }
        else
        {
            vCountAmount = 0;
            vCount = GetComponent<Text>();
            vCount.text = vCountAmount.ToString();
        }
    }

    public void SubtractPrice()
    {
        Debug.Log("subtraction is occuring");
        if (totalCost12 >= 1800)
        {
            totalCost12 -= 1800;
            vCost = GetComponent<Text>();
            vCost.text = totalCost12.ToString();


            Debug.Log(totalCost12);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("majamaja");
            totalCost12 = 0;
            vCost = GetComponent<Text>();
            vCost.text = totalCost12.ToString();
        }
    }

    public void PurchaseVent()
    {
      //  Debug.Log("value copy" +valueCopy);
        Debug.Log("before logic total cost is " + totalCost12);
        economy_worth -= totalCost12;
        

        Debug.Log("Economy after purchase" + economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("total cost is " + totalCost12);

        Covid_PT -= vCountAmount * 60;
        Debug.Log("Pateints after purchase" + Covid_PT);
        Debug.Log("Num of vents: " + vCountAmount);
    }

    //VACCINE PURCHASE
    public void AddCountVac()
    {
        vacCountAmount += 4;
        vacCount = GetComponent<Text>();
        vacCount.text = vacCountAmount.ToString();
        Debug.Log("Num of vaccines: " + vacCountAmount);
    }
    public void AddVaccine()
    {
        totalCostVac += 80 * 4;
        vacCost = GetComponent<Text>();
        vacCost.text = totalCostVac.ToString();
        Debug.Log("total cost is " + totalCostVac);
    }
    public void SubtractCountVac()
    {
        if (vacCountAmount >= 4)
        {
            vacCountAmount -= 4;
            vacCount = GetComponent<Text>();
            vacCount.text = vacCountAmount.ToString();
            Debug.Log("Num of vaccines: " + vacCountAmount);
        }
        else
        {
            vacCountAmount = 0;
            vacCount = GetComponent<Text>();
            vacCount.text = vacCountAmount.ToString();
        }
    }
    public void SubtractVaccine()
    {
        if (totalCostVac >= 80 * 4)
        {
            totalCostVac -= 80 * 4;
            vacCost = GetComponent<Text>();
            vacCost.text = totalCostVac.ToString();
            Debug.Log("total cost is " + totalCostVac);
        }
        else
        {
            totalCostVac = 0;
            vacCost = GetComponent<Text>();
            vacCost.text = totalCostVac.ToString();
        }
    }

    public void PurchaceVaccines()
    {
        Debug.Log("before logic total cost is " + totalCostVac);
        economy_worth -= totalCostVac;
        Debug.Log(economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("total cost is " + totalCostVac);

        Covid_PT -= vacCountAmount * 6 / 4;
        Debug.Log(Covid_PT);
        Debug.Log("Num of vaccines: " + vacCountAmount);
    }
    //MASK PURCHASE
    public void AddCountMask()
    {
        maskCountAmount += 50;
        maskCount = GetComponent<Text>();
        maskCount.text = maskCountAmount.ToString();
        Debug.Log(maskCountAmount);
    }
    public void Addmask()
    {
        totalCostMask += 5 * 50;
        maskCost = GetComponent<Text>();
        maskCost.text = totalCostMask.ToString();
        Debug.Log(totalCostMask);
    }
    public void SubtractCountMask()
    {
        if (maskCountAmount >= 50)
        {
            maskCountAmount -= 50;
            maskCount = GetComponent<Text>();
            maskCount.text = maskCountAmount.ToString();
            Debug.Log(maskCountAmount);

        }
        else
        {
            maskCountAmount = 0;
            maskCount = GetComponent<Text>();
            maskCount.text = maskCountAmount.ToString();
        }
    }
    public void Subtractmask()
    {
        if (totalCostMask >= 5 * 50)
        {
            totalCostMask -= 5 * 50;
            maskCost = GetComponent<Text>();
            maskCost.text = totalCostMask.ToString();
            Debug.Log(totalCostMask);

        }
        else
        {
            totalCostMask = 0;
            maskCost = GetComponent<Text>();
            maskCost.text = totalCostMask.ToString();
        }
    }
    public void PurchaceMasks()
    {
        Debug.Log("before logic total cost is " + totalCostMask);
        economy_worth -= totalCostMask;
        Debug.Log(economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("total cost is " + totalCostMask);

        Covid_PT -= maskCountAmount * 2 / 50;
        Debug.Log(Covid_PT);
        Debug.Log("Num of vaccines: " + maskCountAmount);
    }
    //SHELTER PURCHASE
    public void AddCountShelter()
    {
        shelterCountAmount++;
        shelterCount = GetComponent<Text>();
        shelterCount.text = shelterCountAmount.ToString();
        Debug.Log(shelterCountAmount);
    }
    public void Addshelter()
    {
        totalCostShelter += 1500;
        shelterCost = GetComponent<Text>();
        shelterCost.text = totalCostShelter.ToString();
        Debug.Log(totalCostShelter);
    }
    public void SubtractCountShelter()
    {
        if (shelterCountAmount >= 1)
        {
            shelterCountAmount -= 1;
            shelterCount = GetComponent<Text>();
            shelterCount.text = shelterCountAmount.ToString();
            Debug.Log(shelterCountAmount);
        }
        else
        {
            shelterCountAmount = 0;
            shelterCount = GetComponent<Text>();
            shelterCount.text = shelterCountAmount.ToString();
        }
    }
    public void Subtractshelter()
    {
        if (totalCostShelter >= 1500)
        {
            totalCostShelter -= 1500;
            shelterCost = GetComponent<Text>();
            shelterCost.text = totalCostShelter.ToString();
            Debug.Log(totalCostShelter);
        }
        else
        {
            totalCostShelter = 0;
            shelterCost = GetComponent<Text>();
            shelterCost.text = totalCostShelter.ToString();
        }
    }
    public void PurchaceShelter()
    {
        Debug.Log("before logic total cost is " + totalCostShelter);
        economy_worth -= totalCostShelter;
        Debug.Log(economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("total cost is " + totalCostShelter);

        Covid_PT -= shelterCountAmount * 80;
        Debug.Log(Covid_PT);
        Debug.Log("Num of vaccines: " + shelterCountAmount);
    }
    //RESTRICTION

    public void curfew()
    {
        Debug.Log("Economy Worth before curfew" + economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("Pateints before curfew" + Covid_PT);
        economy_worth -= 50;        
        Invoke("curfew", 1.0f);
        Debug.Log("Economy Worth after curfew" + economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("Patients after curfew" + Covid_PT);
    }
    public void strict()
    {
        Debug.Log("Economy Worth before strict lockdown" + economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("Pateints before strict lockdown" + Covid_PT);
        economy_worth -= 40;
        Covid_PT++;
        Invoke("strict", 1.0f);
        Debug.Log("Economy Worth after strict lockdown" + economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("Patients after strict lockdown" + Covid_PT);
    }
    public void mild()
    {
        Debug.Log("Economy Worth before mild lockdown" + economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("Pateints before mild lockdown" + Covid_PT);
        economy_worth -= 30;
        Covid_PT += 2;
        Invoke("mild", 1.0f);
        Debug.Log("Economy Worth after mild lockdown" + economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("Patients after mild lockdown" + Covid_PT);
    }
    public void smart()
    {
        Debug.Log("Economy Worth before smart lockdown" + economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("Pateints before smart lockdown" + Covid_PT);
        economy_worth -= 15;
        Covid_PT += 3;
        Invoke("smart", 1.0f);
        Debug.Log("Economy Worth after smart lockdown" + economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("Patients after smart lockdown" + Covid_PT);
    }
    public void NoLockdown()
    {
        Debug.Log("Economy Worth before No lockdown" + economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("Pateints before No lockdown" + Covid_PT);
        economy_worth -= 8;
        Covid_PT += 5;
        Invoke("NoLockdown", 1.0f);
        Debug.Log("Economy Worth after No lockdown" + economy_worth);
        Debug.Log("Patients after No lockdown" + Covid_PT);
    }
    //TAX COLLECTION
    
    public void CollectTax()
    {
        
        if (Tax_amount == (int)(0.8 * population))
        {
            Debug.Log("Economy before collection: " + economy_worth);
            Debug.Log("Tax before collection: " + Tax_amount);
            economy_worth += Tax_amount;
//            economyWorth.text = economy_worth.ToString();
           // economyWorth = GetComponent<Text>();
            Tax_amount = 0;
            Debug.Log("Economy after collection: " + economy_worth);
            Debug.Log("Tax after collection: " + Tax_amount);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Tax not collected");
        }
    }
    // S T O R E
    public void item_1()
    {
        Debug.Log("Economy before Purchase" + economy_worth);
        economy_worth += 60000;
        Debug.Log("Economy after Purchase" + economy_worth);
    }
    public void item_2()
    {
        Debug.Log("Economy before Purchase" + economy_worth);
        economy_worth += 30000;
        Debug.Log("Economy after Purchase" + economy_worth);
    }
    public void item_3()
    {
        Debug.Log("Economy before Purchase" + economy_worth);
        economy_worth += 20000;
        Debug.Log("Economy after Purchase" + economy_worth);
    }
    public void item_4()
    {
        Debug.Log("Economy before Purchase" + economy_worth);
        economy_worth += 10000;
        Debug.Log("Economy after Purchase" + economy_worth);
    }


    void Update()
    {  //MARKET
       //  Covid_Budget = (int)(0.01 * economy_worth);
       //  CovidBudget.text = Covid_Budget.ToString();
       // CovidBudget = GetComponent<Text>();

        //Debug.Log(totalCost12.ToString());
    }
    //CLAIM REWARD
    public void Claim_1st()
    {
        if (claim1st!=0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Economy before reward" + economy_worth);
            economy_worth += claim1st;
            Debug.Log("Economy after reward" + economy_worth);
            claim1st = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Award can't be claimed as it is: " + claim1st);
        }
    }
    public void Claim_2nd()
    {
        if (claim2nd != 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Economy before reward" + economy_worth);
            economy_worth += claim2nd;
            Debug.Log("Economy after reward" + economy_worth);
            claim2nd = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Award can't be claimed as it is: " + claim2nd);
        }
    }
    public void Claim_3rd()
    {
        if (claim3rd != 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Economy before reward" + economy_worth);
            economy_worth += claim3rd;
            Debug.Log("Economy after reward" + economy_worth);
            claim3rd = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Award can't be claimed as it is: " + claim3rd);
        }

    }
    public void Claim_4th()
    {
        if (claim4th != 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Economy before reward" + economy_worth);
            economy_worth += claim4th;
            Debug.Log("Economy after reward" + economy_worth);
            claim4th = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Award can't be claimed as it is: " + claim4th);
        }
    }
    public void Claim_5th()
    {
        if (claim5th != 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Economy before reward" + economy_worth);
            economy_worth += claim5th;
            Debug.Log("Economy after reward" + economy_worth);
            claim5th = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Award can't be claimed as it is: " + claim5th);
        }

    }
    public void Claim_6th()
    {
        if (claim6th != 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Economy before reward" + economy_worth);
            economy_worth += claim6th;
            Debug.Log("Economy after reward" + economy_worth);
            claim6th = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Award can't be claimed as it is: " + claim6th);
        }
    }

    }



    public void Awake()
    {   //NATIONAL BANK
        economy_worth = 900000;
        //Covid
        Covid_PT = 9000;
        //POPULATION
        population = 160000;
        //TAX COLLECTION
        Tax_amount = (int)(0.8 * population);
    }
}
```

Comment: From the code you showed everything seems okay. Show full code

Comment: okay, 've added full code in end please check.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make all the variables private, then look if any other code is accessing those variables that you forgot about. I just replicated the same code in a console app and it seems to be okay for me. Make all variables public and see whats accessing it because that should be the only issue that i can possibly see.